# Starting an android project in VScode using a generated template

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

After some search on how to migrate from Android Studio to VScode, I finally got my app running on a virtual device and all is good without Android Studio, but the issue is that I`m a beginner and I kinda don`t know what every build or project file do exactly, I just start with a base empty  template that Android Studio generates. My question is, is there any way I can generate that template in VScode? until I learn how to create them myself.